# NCORE tag when performing hybrid-functional calculations

Tags: vasp, hse06

Do you set `NCORE` when performing hybrid-functional calculations?

I heard that `NCORE` can be set for VASP6, but when I do ***not*** set them, I still get the warning: "Unfortunately you need to use the default for GW and RPA calculations (for HF `NCORE` is supported but not extensively tested yet)". From this warning, it seems `NCORE` should not be set for hybrid-functional calculations even with VASP6.

Comment: What warning it is, did you tried changing NCORE=number of processor per node or 4 or 8